# PHP preg_replace only muptiple occurrences

Tags: php, preg-replace

this following code will replaces spaces correctly:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/", "", $string);
```

but how can I make it so that it will only replace it if there is more than 2 blank spaces?  Because right now it replaces all spaces, I only need it to replace more than one space.  I searched on here and see people use totally different preg_replace codes, but it also removes newlines so if the code I posted can just be simply modified to allow more than one blank, that would be great.  I remember a while back reading a tutorial where it used something like `{2+}` in the preg area to match anything with more than two or something but not sure how to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/[[:blank:]]{2,}/`

That will make it replace sequences of two or more.

The [php manual has a chapter about repetition/quantifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/", " ", $string);
```

Same as yours but replaces all occurrences of spaces with one space.